# Database inheritance Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am looking forward to implement a website dealing with teachers, students and parents. In the database I made, I've created a `user` table and 3 children tables : `teachers`, `students`, `parents`.
See below the table structure

```
User table
+--------+----------+----------+-------+
| id (PK)| username | password | email |
+--------+----------+----------+-------+
| 1      | user1    | 123      | ...   |
+--------+----------+----------+-------+
| 2      | user2    | 132      | ...   |
+--------+----------+----------+-------+
| 3      | user3    | 321      | ...   |
+--------+----------+----------+-------+

Student table
+---------------+--------------+
| users_id (PK) | class        |
+---------------+--------------+
| 1             | highschool   |
+---------------+--------------+
| 3             | middleschool |
+---------------+--------------+
Teacher table
+--------------+-------------------+---------------------+
| users_id (PK)| subscription_type | end_of_subscription |
+--------------+-------------------+---------------------+
| 2            | monthly           | 2017-10-25          |
+--------------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

And the parents table also have a PK which corresponds to a user id. 
I just started to learn laravel and I really wonder how could I handle this properly  maybe with eloquent with Laravel 5.4.

Comment: Where is the FK of User table in student table and teacher table

Comment: The FK is on the `users_id`. `users_id` is the PK for table `users, teachers` and `parents`, but also a FK which refers to the users.

Comment: Made a mistake on the above comment :  
`users_id` is the PK for table `students, teachers` and `parents`, but also a FK which refers to the users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am giving you some hints I think you can do rest and as your question is not specific I am guessing you are thinking how can you relate/join tables, so

1. Create three model let say `User, Student, Teacher`.
2. In Student & Teacher model create a method like below

> ```
> public function user()
> {
>   return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'users_id');
> }
> ```

Now you can query like :

```
$student = Student::find($id) ;
$name = $student->user->name;
$email = $student->user->email ;
Or 
$teachers = Teacher::where('subscription_type', 'monthly')->with(['user'])->get();
dd($teachers);
```

> I think you need to update your database structure, you need pk & fk
>   column separated.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help :) It solves my problem. And thanks for your advise i'll implement a new id column as FK. Bye